SVG Icon Taking Long to Reflect on Google
I have a Vite React app, and I've recently updated my favicon to an SVG file. However, it seems to be taking a long time for this change to be reflected on Google. Here are the details of my setup, I can't find what was the problem, Is it usauly take some time or there is any error in my code
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100..900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>King Tech Builders</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


Below I uploaded screen shot of my client's website, it show's a  unkown logo, I did't used that logo.
screen shot of my client website
